# collectFirst with match clause in partial function

Tags: scala

I am wondering if and how I can use a match clause within a collectFirst clause in scala. So for example I want to do something like the following:

```
myCollection collectFirst {
  case i =>
    otherCollection.find(_ == i + 1) match {
      case Some(j) => j
      case None => // Check the next i???
  }
}
```

Note I know I could achieve the above logic without the match clause but am doing it this way purely for explanatory purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined a function as follows:

```
def mapFirst[A, B](seq: Seq[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = seq match {
  case Seq(a, rest @ _ *) =>
    f(a) match {
      case Some(b) => Some(b)
      case None => mapFirst(rest)(f)
    }
    case _ => None
}
```

Which could be used thus:

```
  mapFirst(myCollection) { i => 
    otherCollection.find(_ == i + 1) match {
      case Some(j) => Some(j)
      case None => None
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
val other = List(4)
List(1, 2, 3, 4) collectFirst {
  case i if other.contains(i) => s"other has $i"
}

res0: Option[String] = Some(other has 4)
```

---

> Note I know I could achieve the above logic without the match clause
>   but am doing it this way purely for explanatory purposes

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4) collectFirst {
  case i if (other.find(_ == i) match {
    case Some(_) => true
    case None => false
  }) => s"other has $i"
}
```

**don't do that in your code!**